# Magento 2 - Create csv file for download in admin

Tags: magento2, admin, uicomponent, controllers

**I need to create a file in mangento 2 admin.**

I'm using a button to get in a controller route.

My form ui component:

```
<item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Report\Edit\ExportButton</item>
</item>
```

I used a dummy data provider just for use the submit url:

```
<dataSource name="bvz_report_specifier_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Form\DummyDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">bvz_report_specifier_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/export"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
```

In Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Export I creat an csv file and save it and put the name of file in URL.

**Now I need to download this file when the page refresh.**

In the index controller I have this code to make the download:

```
if($fileName = $this->getRequest()->getParam('file')){

            $url = $mediaUrl = $this ->_storeManager-> getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA );
            $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
            return $resultRedirect->setUrl($url.$fileName);
        }
```

The download happens but my page goes to infinite load. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

So I *think* this is caused by the response body being empty when it contains a downloadable link. However, when I added dummy content to the response the spinner still wouldn't disappear

I did manage to resolve this by returning `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory::create` in my admin controller:

```php
return $this->fileFactory->create(
    $fileName,
    [
        'type' => 'filename',
        'value' => $filePath,
        'rm' => true  // can delete file after use
    ],
    DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
    'text/csv'
);
```

Then implementing a bit of JS in `app/code/MyTestProject/Ui/view/base/requirejs-config.js`:

```js
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Ui/js/form/client': {
                'MyTestProject_Ui/js/form/client-mixin': true
            },
        }
    }
};
```

And `app/code/MyTestProject/Ui/view/base/web/js/form/client-mixin.js`:

```js
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
], function ($, _, utils) {
    'use strict';

    return function (OriginalClient) {
        return OriginalClient.extend({
            /**
             * Save data.
             *
             * @param {Object} data
             * @param {Object} options
             * @returns {Object}
             * @private
             */
            _save: function(data, options) {
                var url = this.urls.save;

                $('body').trigger('processStart');
                options = options || {};

                if (!options.redirect) {
                    url += 'back/edit';
                }

                if (options.ajaxSave) {
                    utils.ajaxSubmit({
                        url: url,
                        data: data
                    }, options);

                    return this;
                }

                utils.submit({
                    url: url,
                    data: data
                }, options.attributes);

                // CUSTOMISATION BEGINS HERE
                if (options.attributes.id === "test_csv_generating_form") {
                    $('body').trigger('processStop');
                }
                // CUSTOMISATION ENDS HERE

                return this;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You'll have to replace `"test_csv_generating_form"` in the example above with the name of your UI component XML file.

This has been tested and works in Magento `2.4.3-p1`.

Answer (score 0):

I crate a Admin Grid using Ui-Component.

You  want all Data you have create a Custom Export  Button that export your all data.

edit in your Ui-Component file where  Admin Grid Show

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \view\adminhtml\ui_component**

Add this code to add Button into Admin Grid

***Ui-ComponentFIleName.xml***

```
<item name="import" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="name" xsi:type="string">import</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Import</item>
    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
</item>

<item name="export" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="name" xsi:type="string">export</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Export</item>
    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">secondary</item>
    <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
</item>
```

**Now create a File that Export or Import Data. File Name must be same as you define in Ui-Component file**

```
  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/exportdata</item>

  <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/importdata</item>
```

File path must be like this

**[vendor_name] \ [module_name] \ Controller \ Adminhtml \ [Controller_name] \ Exportdata.php**

***Exportdata.php***

```
<?php

namespace [vendor_name]\[module_name]\Controller\Adminhtml\[Controller_name];

use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;


class Exportdata extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $uploaderFactory;

    protected $_locationFactory; 

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\FileFactory $fileFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        \[vendor_name]\[module_name]\Model\locatorFactory $locationFactory // This is returns Collaction of Data

    ) {
       parent::__construct($context);
       $this->_fileFactory = $fileFactory;
       $this->_locationFactory = $locationFactory;
       $this->directory = $filesystem->getDirectoryWrite(DirectoryList::VAR_DIR); // VAR Directory Path
       parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {   
        $name = date('m-d-Y-H-i-s');
        $filepath = 'export/export-data-' .$name. '.csv'; // at Directory path Create a Folder Export and FIle
        $this->directory->create('export');

        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();

        //column name dispay in your CSV 

        $columns = ['Col-1-name','Col-2-name','Col-3-name','Col-4-name','Col-5-name','Col-6-name','Col-7-name','Col-8-name','Col-9-name',];

            foreach ($columns as $column) 
            {
                $header[] = $column; //storecolumn in Header array
            }

        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $location = $this->_locationFactory->create();
        $location_collection = $location->getCollection(); // get Collection of Table data 

        foreach($location_collection as $item){

            $itemData = [];

            // column name must same as in your Database Table 

            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-1-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-2-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-3-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-4-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-5-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-6-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-7-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-8-name');
            $itemData[] = $item->getData('col-9-name');

            $stream->writeCsv($itemData);

        }

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename'; // must keep filename
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1'; //remove csv from var folder

        $csvfilename = 'locator-import-'.$name.'.csv';
        return $this->_fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);

    }


}
```

Now you can Click on the Export Button and See your .csv file Downloaded below.

***I Hope This Helps You.***

Comment: he asks about the loading infinitive not about the download part so your answer doesn't help