# magento 2 admin create and download csv file and loading problem

Tags: magento2, csv, admin-controller, download

Please loading issue solve. I try to reload or redirect but that is not working.

```
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setPath('*/*/');
        return $resultRedirect;
```

My code is ->

```
        $name = date('m_d_Y_H_i_s');
        $filepath = 'export/custom' . $name . '.csv';
        $this->directory->create('export');
        /* Open file */
        $stream = $this->directory->openFile($filepath, 'w+');
        $stream->lock();
        $columns = $this->SalesData->getAllExcelHeaderName();
        foreach ($columns as $column) {
            $header[] = $column;
        }
        /* Write Header */
        $stream->writeCsv($header);

        $products[] = array(1, 'Test 1', 'test 1', 100);
        $products[] = array(2, 'Test 2', 'test 2', 299);

        foreach ($products as $item) {
            $itemData = [];
            $itemData[] = $item[0];
            $itemData[] = $item[1];
            $itemData[] = $item[2];
            $itemData[] = $item[3];
            $stream->writeCsv($itemData);
        }

        $content = [];
        $content['type'] = 'filename';
        $content['value'] = $filepath;
        $content['rm'] = '1';

        $csvfilename = 'Product.csv';
        $this->_fileFactory->create($csvfilename, $content, DirectoryList::VAR_DIR);
```

[image]

Comment: Please share the details of error.

Comment: Please refer to the below link. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/282160/magento-2-create-csv-file-for-download-in-admin

Comment: update the question. loading issue

Answer (score 0):

Please check below for main issue cause.

1. Check the browser `console` and `network` tab.
2. Check the Magento log from `var/log/` dir.
3. Check the server log.